# AS3 - Why does setting a DisplayObject's alpha to 0.7 actually results in the alpha being set to 0.69921875?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

At one point in my code I set a Sprite's alpha to 0.7

`square.alpha = 0.7;`

Later in my code, I check for this alpha in a conditional statement.

`if (square.alpha == 0.7) {//do stuff}`

I was scratching my head why it wasn't working until I did a `trace(square.alpha);` and instead of `0.7` I got `0.69921875`.

This number (`0.69921875`) was the same for each instance of the sprite that I set to have an alpha of 0.7.

I did a few tests and it looks like the only values of `alpha` that return exactly the same value as I set them are `0`, `0.5`, and `1`. Anything else seems to always return a number that is very very close to what I set it to, but not quite. For example `0.2` will give me `0.19921875`

Why does this happen?

I use Flex to compile the code, not sure if that has any affect on this.

Comment: Actually, checking floating-point numbers for equality always returns false, except for 0 and, in some cases, integer values. So just don't.

Comment: @Vesper What? No it doesn't. I understand what you are trying to say but this is statement is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @EthanWorley I mean if `a` is a float, and `b` is another float, checking `if (a==b)` will return false if either a or b is calculated. The rest is compiler dependant, say Turbo Pascal with `{$N+}` on yielded false on `var a:double; begin a:=2.0; writeln(a=2.0);` but true if a was of type extended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alpha is stored as an 8 bit channel under the hood. The number is due to the float -> 8-bit int -> float conversion.

Here's the math:

```
256 * 0.7 = 179 (179.2 rounded) // converting from float to 8bit int
179 / 256 = 0.69921875          // converting from int back to float
```

It's not due to the limitation of floating point numbers as the others have suggested.

The reason that 0, 0.5, and 1 work correctly is that these are fractions that don't undergo any rounding when converted to an 8 bit int.

for example:

```
256 * 0.5 = 128 (no rounding necessary)
128 / 256 = 0.5
```

If you want a work around, you could set your alpha to a fraction of 256, and check it against the same fraction:

```
square.alpha = 179 / 256;

if (square.alpha == 179 / 256) {/*do stuff*/}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same limitation as with floating point numbers. It's interesting that alpha is stored this way internally (and that explains why the rounding error is larger than with IEEE floats), but the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: I agree with you that the nature of the limitation is the same. I disagree that the problem Garry is experiencing is caused by the limitation of floats.

Comment: Oh, this explains it, and it also explains why 0.7 compared to square.alpha (which was set to 0.7 previously) don't match since the 0.7 constant doesn't get converted to 8-bit int and back to float like the alpha. But if I had two sprites both with alphas set to 0.7, comparing them would give me equal.

And it's also good to know that in this particular case the final number of the alpha will be the same on all computers, rather than possibly be different depending on what chip the computer has as in the case of floating point precision?

Answer (score 2):

That's a general limitation of floating point numbers. Just as you can't express `1/3` in the decimal system exactly (`0.33333333....` etc.), you can't express (decimal) `0.1` as a binary floating point number exactly (`0.00011001100110011001100110011...` etc.).

You *can* express decimal `0.5` as a binary float exactly (`0.1`), as well as `0.25` (`0.01`) and other fractions that have a power of 2 in the denominator. That's why you saw a correct result for `0.5`, but not for the others.

[This part of the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about alpha... It's about floating point arithmetic. The way computers stores floating point numbers, some numbers just tend be close to what you want to store. You can find more details in this question: [Why am I seeing inexact floating-point results in ECMAScript / ActionScript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597224/why-am-i-seeing-inexact-floating-point-results-in-ecmascript-actionscript-3)